# SQL: How to extract data from one column as different columns, according to different condition?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have many access points, each AP has two RF cards, each RF card has a channel number.

```
AP_idx | RF_idx | Channel |
   0   |    0   |    7    |
   0   |    1   |    136  |
   1   |    0   |    11   |
   1   |    1   |    128  |
   2   |    0   |    4    |
   2   |    1   |    149  |
```

Now I need a mapping between AP_idx and (RF0 channel, RF1 channel), see the following example

```
AP_idx | ChannelA | ChannelB |
   0   |    7     |    136   |
   1   |    11    |    128   |
   2   |    4     |    149   |
```

I want channel as channelA, when RF_idx == 0, and channel as channelB when RF_idx == 1

How do I design the SQL statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to "pivot" the data.  In SQLite, one way to do this by using `group by`:

```
select AP_idx,
       max(case when RF_idx = 0 then Channel end) as ChannelA,
       max(case when RF_idx = 1 then Channel end) as ChannelB
from table t
group by AP_idx;
```

Another way is by using `join`:

```
select ta.AP_idx, ta.channel as ChannelA, tb.channel as ChannelB
from table ta join
     table tb
     on ta.AP_idx = tb.AP_idx and
        ta.RF_idx = 0 and
        tb.RF_idx = 1;
```

This might have better performance with the right indexes.  On the other hand, the aggregation method is safer if some of the channel values are missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
select AP_idx, ChannelA, ChannelB
from (select AP_idx, Channel AS ChannelA WHERE RF_idx = 0) AS T1
inner join
(select AP_idx, Channel AS ChannelB WHERE RF_idx = 1) AS T2
using (AP_idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL:

```
select a.AP_idx, a.Channel, b.Channel
  from (select AP_idx, RF_idx, Channel from t where RF_idx = 0) as a,
       (select AP_idx, RF_idx, Channel from t where RF_idx = 1) as b
 where a.AP_idx = b.AP_idx;
```

Result:

```
0|7|136
1|11|128
2|4|149
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display a different field as channel depending on one field. The syntax would be

```
select AP_idx, 
    RF_idx, 
    case RF_ixd
        when 0 then ChannelA
        else ChannelB
        end as channel
from mytable
```

if you need to map the channel field to different columns then you could try

```
select AP_idx, 
    sum(case RF_ixd
        when 0 then channel
        else 0
        end) as channelA,
    sum(case RF_ixd
        when 1 then channel
        else 0
        end) as channelB
from mytable
group by RF_idx
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```
select T1.Ap_idx,T1.RF_idx, Case RF_idx WHEN 0 THEN T2.ChannelA ELSE T2.ChannelB END As Channel
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
Table2 T2 on T1.AP_idx=T2.AP_idx
```

Result:

```
AP_idx  RF_idx  Channel
0        0       7
0        1       136
1        0       11
1        1       128
2        0       4
2        1       149
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the table name is APinfo.

SELECT ap_idx,
sum(case when RF_idx =0 THEN Channel ELSE 0 END) as 'ChannelA', 
sum(case when RF_idx =1 THEN Channel ELSE 0 END) as 'ChannelB'
from ap_idx
group by ap_idx

These conditional statements depend on the DB you are on.